# Actionlistener java

Tags: java, actionlistener

For my class I need to use my ActionListener. I am having trouble adding my ActionListener to my buttons. I have to use the word "this" like this.buttons to add my ActionListener but Im having trouble doing that. I will get to my actionPerformed method later but my main problem is my ActionListener.

```
public class TextButtonsHW extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JButton[] buttons;  //Do not change
private JTextArea textArea; //Do not change
//Assign values for these constants in the constructor
private final int ENTER;    //Index of Enter button in buttons
private final int SPACE;    //Index of Space button in buttons
private final int CLEAR;    //Index of Clear button in buttons

/**
 * Set up this frame and its contents.
 * @param title Title to appear in JFrame title bar
 */
public TextButtonsHW(String title) {

    super(title); //call parent JFrame constructor to set the title

    buttons = new JButton[] { new JButton("A"), new JButton("B"), new JButton("C"),
                  new JButton("1"), new JButton("2"), new JButton("3"),
                  new JButton("X"), new JButton("Y"), new JButton("Z"),
                  new JButton("Enter"), new JButton("Space"), new JButton("Clear")};

    ENTER = buttons.length-3;
    SPACE = buttons.length-2;
    CLEAR = buttons.length-1;

    textArea = new JTextArea(15, 5);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    this.buttons[0].addActionListener(I dont know what to put right here);

    //TODO: instantiate all JButtons, add them to the buttons array,
    //  and register "this" as the ActionListener for each button.
    //DONE
    //TODO: assign values to ENTER, SPACE, and CLEAR constants to
    //  indicate the indexes of those buttons in the buttons array
    //DONE
    //TODO: create the JTextArea textArea
    //TODO: set its "editable" property to false
    //DONE
    //Create a TextButtonsHWPanel to display the buttons and textArea

    TextButtonsHWPanel mainPanel = new TextButtonsHWPanel(buttons, textArea);
    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    this.pack();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    //TODO: update the text of textArea according to which
    //  button generated the ActionEvent.

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final TextButtonsHW f = new TextButtonsHW("Text Buttons");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //centers frame on screen
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: It's better if you make ENTER. SPACE, CLEAR type enum rather than int.

Comment: I see how it could be but my assignment wants it like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: remember the parameter of addActionListener is a class that implements the actionPerformed method, which in this case is the same class that defines addActionListner and hence the "this".

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 12 buttons you could also go for a for-loop to add ActionListener to all your buttons i.e.

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
}
```

Instead of a long code i.e.

```
buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
buttons[1].addActionListener(this);
........................
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `buttons[0].addActionListener(this);` will work well, From design perspective I will suggest to have separate class (may be inner class) which implements `ActionListner` and pass its object reference to the method.

the whole point of Object Oriented programming is to delegate different responsibilities to different Objects(classes), so code becomes more maintainable and reusable.